# Cannot change value on input after axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-bootstrap

```
    const [something, setSomething] = useState({
        Name: "getbyID.Name",
        Category: "",
        type: "",
        Description: "",
        className: '',
        start: '',
        TargetDate: ''
    });
    const handleChangeInput= async function(event) {
        console.log("Value from event:", event.target.value);
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setSomething({
            ...something,
            [name]: value
        });}
    useEffect(() => {
        var data = {
            "resource": "",
            "action": "get",
            "params": {
                "Id__eq": handleSelected,
            }
        };
        if (handleSelected) {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: '',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    Auth: auth.user.token
                },
                contentType: "json",
                dataType: "json",
            }).then((response) => {
                setGetbyID(response.data[0]);
                set(response.data[0]);
                var prevData = response.data[0];
            })
        }
    }, [handleSelected]) 
    <Form.Check inline label = "Professional" value = "Professional" name = "Category" type = "radio" id = "Category-1" onChange = {handleChangeInput}onClick = {FormHandlerProfessional}/> 

< Form.Check inline label = ""value = ""name = "Category" type = "radio" onChange = {handleChangeInput}/> < /div> 


< SmallCalendar onChange = {handleChangeInput}value = {something.TargetDate}/>
```

After getting values from Axios call I can't change the values from locking on the axios value and can't update the input text values are working correctly.

The handling is done in handleChangeInput and on it's fired on on change listener

The problem is on radio button and datepicker only

Comment: Don't use useEffect hook within handleChangeInput. Hook should always be called at top level. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: Write your code in online compiler and add link here for better understanding. @Giorgos Georgantas

Comment: It's hard to tell only see your half of the code.